# Locate focus_distance from camera for Depth of Field

Tags: python

I've got a camera setup with depth of field turned on. I'd like to draw things in Python along specific plane facing the camera at the distance of the `focus_distance`

```
import bpy

loc, rot, scale = bpy.context.scene.camera.matrix_world.decompose()
focus_distance =  bpy.scene.camera.data.dof.focus_distance

#get vector of focus_distance
```

Comment: `direction = (rot @ type(loc)((0, 0, -1))).normalized() * focus_distance`

Comment: @x-y looks like ```((rot @ type(loc)((0, 0, -1))).normalized() * focus_distance) + camera.location``` needing to add the camera location to match whats shown in the UI.